# Where to put validation group interface?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have code like this:

```
@PutMapping("/create")
public void create(@RequestBody @Validated(MyValidationGroup.class) MyDto myDto) {
...
}
```

As you can see I use validation group for validation. My question related with code organization.I don't have ideas where to put validation group interface. Where to put interface `MyValidationGroup`?

Comment: Can you please specify the purpose of this validation? After that i can provide you a solution for that.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 It defines which rules to use for validation

Comment: I have added few points might help you.